# How can I format the output in an error message in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I would like to present an error message to the user in my R function for a specifc error. For that I created an output as tibble. Let's assume:

```
err_out = tibble(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4)) 
stop("Error X happend:", err_out)
```

I get `Error: Error X happend:c(1, 2)c(3, 4)` But I would prefer the typical representation of the tibble, i.e.

```
Error: Error X happend:
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     3
 2     2     4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
err_out = tibble(a=c(1,2), b=c(3,4))
stop("Error X happened:\n", paste(capture.output(err_out), collapse = "\n"))
# Error: Error X happened:
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#       a     b
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3
# 2     2     4
```

If you do this frequently, you might want to wrap it up in a utility function.